# Is there an easy way to tell which proprietary blobs my system uses?

Tags: firmware, proprietary

I understand Ubuntu puts the proprietary blobs in the linux-firmware package which contains a LOT of files. Is there an easy way to tell which of these blobs my system actually uses?